# hola quiero saber como presiono la tecla enter con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

tengo el siguiente codigo

```
document.querySelector("#contenteditable-root").click;
document.querySelector("#contenteditable-root").textContent="hola ";
```

pero quiero que al final de agregar el texto al elemento presione la tecla enter tambien puede ser otra tecla

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Con que propósito quieres eso?  Si es para reproducir un evento que luego haga alguna cosa no te hace falta, desde javascript ya puedes reproducirlo seguramente, tan solo debes poner a continuación del textContent lo que quieres hacer después.